# How to populate through array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have  a data like follows

```
 "student" : [ 
ObjectId("58500ea5ef914125073b040f"),
ObjectId("58500ea5ef914125073b042e")

],
```

my model,

```
  student: [{type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Student'}],
```

I want to populate student in these array,

```
  Classroom.findById(id).populate('student.student'){}
```

It is not working,can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Did you add ref to your model's schema `student:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }]`

Comment: Yes i did it.....

Comment: Could you show your schemas' code, and make sure you have appropriate data to populate in db.

Comment: Please post your Classroom schema.

Comment: Hi posted my schema.

Comment: Yes styopdev ,i have record with that student id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see in your data, `student` is the `array` of students, so you need to just write `student` in the `populate` query.

this should work for you :

```
Classroom.findById(id).populate('student').exec(function(err,result){
    ...
});
```