# How to populate through array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a record like this,

```
"student" : [ 
  ObjectId("5850e76196d4de3c1f4a0618"), 
  ObjectId("5850da3e7f3ff224767c196c")
],
```

I tried,

```
Classroom.findById(id).populate('student')
```

Can anyone suggest me that, how can I populate through this array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate through array of objects in mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135110/how-to-populate-through-array-of-objects-in-mongoose)

Comment: Please dont duplicate your questions, just edit them.

Comment: Hi styopdev,i just added model like in my code.